# Find entity entry using entity type and key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

How to find tracked entity based on it's key value and entity type?

I mean something simmilar to `DbSet<TEntity>.Find(params object keys):`
e.g.:

```
object[] keys = ....;
dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Local.Find(keys)
//or
dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>().Find(keys);
```

I could create my own `Func<TEntity, bool> predicate` using System.Linq.Expressions from entity metadata, but it is untrivial and maybe there is already something built in.

EDIT:

1. There is a feature request on github for this: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7391. You can vote for it.
2. I came with this simple solution (thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv's answer):

   ```
    public static EntityEntry<TEntity> LocalEntryByPk<TEntity>(this DbContext dbContext, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        EntityEntry<TEntity> entry = dbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (entry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            return entry;
        }
        IKey key = entry.Metadata.FindPrimaryKey() ?? entry.Metadata.GetKeys().FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Key not found");
        object[] keyValues = key.Properties.Select(p => entry.CurrentValues[p]).ToArray();

        //with Internal API (IStateManager)
        var internalEntityEntry = dbContext.GetService<IStateManager>().TryGetEntry(key, keyValues);
        if (internalEntityEntry == null) return null;
        return new EntityEntry<TEntity>(internalEntry);


        //without internal API
        //return dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(e => pk.Properties.All(p => Equals(entry.CurrentValues[p], e.CurrentValues[p])));
    }
   ```

Comment: I have not found standard way. But I can extract from my project effective solution based on compiled expressions.

Comment: Simple question. From where you've get keys array? How do you know order of composite key fields? Does these values are extracted from entity?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: mostly, I extract them from entity using entity metadata:
`EntityEntry.Metadata.GetKeys().FirstOrDefault(key => key.IsPrimaryKey())?.Properties.Select(property => EntityEntry.CurrentValues[property])`

Comment: Just 'dbContext.Entry(entity)' is not a solution. You will return back to my implementation ;)

Comment: It's not just that. I also use StateManager in case the entity instance is not tracked

Answer (score 3):

Check the following implementation, it has functionality for retrieving local entity Entry and sample how to update entity without worrying about exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Some'
> cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value
> '{SomeId: 1}' is already being tracked.

Sample usage:

```cs
var entry = context.FindLocalEntry(someObj);
if (entry == null)
   // someObj is not tracked
```

```cs
// updating
var entry = context.UpdateSafe(someObj);
```

And implementation:

```cs
#pragma warning disable EF1001 // Internal EF Core API usage.

public static class ChangeTrackerHelpers
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<(IModel model, IEntityType entityType), Func<IStateManager, object, InternalEntityEntry?>?> EntityKeyGetterCache = new();

    private static readonly MethodInfo TryGetEntryMethodInfo =
        typeof(IStateManager).GetMethods().First(mi =>
            mi.Name == nameof(IStateManager.TryGetEntry) && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&
            mi.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(IKey));

    private static Func<IStateManager, object, InternalEntityEntry?>? CreateEntityRetrievalFunc(IEntityType entityType)
    {
        var stateManagerParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IStateManager), "sm");
        var objParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "o");

        var variable = Expression.Variable(entityType.ClrType, "e");
        var assignExpr = Expression.Assign(variable, Expression.Convert(objParam, entityType.ClrType));

        var key = entityType.GetKeys().FirstOrDefault();

        if (key == null)
            return null;

        var arrayExpr = key.Properties.Where(p => p.PropertyInfo != null || p.FieldInfo != null).Select(p =>
                Expression.Convert(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(variable, p.PropertyInfo ?? (MemberInfo)p.FieldInfo),
                    typeof(object)))
            .ToArray();

        if (arrayExpr.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (arrayExpr.Length != key.Properties.Count)
            return null;

        var newArrayExpression = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), arrayExpr);
        var body =
            Expression.Block(new[] { variable },
                assignExpr,
                Expression.Call(stateManagerParam, TryGetEntryMethodInfo, Expression.Constant(key),
                    newArrayExpression));

        var lambda =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<IStateManager, object, InternalEntityEntry?>>(body, stateManagerParam, objParam);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }

    private static Func<IStateManager, object, InternalEntityEntry?> GetEntityRetrievalFunc(IModel model,
        IEntityType entityType)
    {
        var func = EntityKeyGetterCache.GetOrAdd((model, entityType),
            key => CreateEntityRetrievalFunc(key.entityType));

        if (func == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not retrieve key information from '{entityType.Name}'.");

        return func;
    }

    public static EntityEntry<TEntity>? FindLocalEntry<TEntity>(this DbContext context, TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
        if (entityType == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Entity type '{typeof(TEntity).Name}' is not registered in model.");

        var stateManager = context.GetService<IStateManager>();

        var func = GetEntityRetrievalFunc(context.Model, entityType);
        var internalEntry = func(stateManager, entity);

        if (internalEntry == null)
            return null;

        return new EntityEntry<TEntity>(internalEntry);
    }

    public static EntityEntry<TEntity> UpdateSafe<TEntity>(this DbContext context, TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var currentEntity = context.FindLocalEntry(entity);

        if (currentEntity != null)
        {
            // Entity already in ChangeTracker, just copy properties if is not the same object
            if (!ReferenceEquals(currentEntity.Entity, entity))
            {
                currentEntity.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Use standard function to attach entity
            currentEntity = context.Update(entity);
        }

        return currentEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but I will not mark it as answer just yet. It will not work with composite primary keys and [alternate keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys).

Comment: With composite it should work, isn't?. But yes currently it checks only one Key.

Comment: You are right, it should work with composite PK, my bad. Since you use `IStateManager.TryGetEntry()`, I somehow miss the point of using System.Expression. Check EDIT in my question.

Comment: I have extracted this code from [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) It was critical to make it fast as possible. That's why dynamic Expression Tree generation.