# EF Core Get tracked entity by clone

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Simple question: How can I get a tracked entity using a clone (same primary key values). Because of mapping, I don't have the tracked entity but a clone of it. It does not matter how to get the clone if using IClonable or Mapping like Mapster (Adapt to the same type, or in my case the base type). I want to prevent having to execute a query if not necessary.

What I tried:

```
dbContext.Entry(clone) // ---> Always detached even if a tracked entity exists
dbContext.Table.FindAsync(clone) // ---> Crashed because clone is no primary key value
```

Of cause I could use `dbContext.Table.FindAsync([primary/composite key values])`. But what if the composite key changes in a migration. For example when you migrate from MySQL to Postgres and you store e.g. a GPS coordinate not in Lat/Lng but in a Point object.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438914/10646316)

Comment: Thx. Already wrote a simple solution myself without the `IStateManager` which is part of the internal API...

Comment: @MarcelLorenz But in that simple solution you effectively implemented `dbContext.Table.FindAsync([primary/composite key values])` with just key values extracted from entity instance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions {
    public static async Task<TEntity?> FindTrackedAsync<TEntity>(this DbContext context, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class {
        var entityType = context.Model.FindRuntimeEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
        var keyProperties = entityType?.FindPrimaryKey()?.Properties;

        if (keyProperties is null)
            return null;

        var keyValues = keyProperties.Select(prop => prop.GetGetter().GetClrValue(entity)).ToArray();
        return await context.FindAsync<TEntity>(keyValues);
    }
}
```