# The instance of entity type 'IdentityUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I created a simple project with Identity. And there is a problem while updating IdentityUser via UserManager.

> The instance of entity type 'IdentityUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

There is a simple controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public UserController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IList<IdentityUser>> Get()
    {
        return await _userManager.Users.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] IdentityUser user)
    {
        return Ok(await _userManager.CreateAsync(user));
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Put([FromBody] IdentityUser user)
    {
        return Ok(await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user));
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices method :

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalConnStr"));
});

services.ConfigureIdentity();
services.AddAuthentication();

services.AddControllers();
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: This is very common exception. Change entity properties returned by `Find` method. Otherwise, if you attach entities, you have to fight with ChangeTracker which has already cached entities. Anyway maybe my function [UpdateSafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438914/10646316) may help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Write an answer i will mark it.

Comment: Just upvote implementation, not sure it is right to duplicate code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `AsNoThacking` method in queries didn't work when I used `AddDbContextFactor` and also the `UserManager`.

I found this record and it helped:

```c
services.AddDbContextFactory<DataContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(conString).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(
    QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking
  ),
  ServiceLifetime.Scoped
);

services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(conString).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(
    QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking
  )
);
```