# Update an entity in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have these two entities:

```
public class TblUser
{
    public long Userid { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblNotify> TblNotifies { get; set; }
}

public partial class TblNotify
{
    public Guid NotifyId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public virtual TblUser ApprovalUser { get; set; }
}
```

The table `tblNotify` has a foreign key `Userid`.

`DbContext` was initially built as singleton service.

I call an update method:

```
uow.GetRepository<tblNotify>().Update(item);
```

It almost always updates successfully, but rarely, I got this error:

> The instance of entity type 'Tbluser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Userid'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

It's weird because I only update the `tblNotify` table. How could I investigate this error further?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856073/the-instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-of-this-t)

Comment: thank Wolf G for your support, but I don't know why I update this entity but impact to related-entity.

Comment: I think I see the problem. This will answer your question. (Hopefully). Please refer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204159/4393935

Comment: I would suggest to use this method [UpdateSafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438914/10646316), which will do all needed preparation for update. Actually it searches for already loaded entities and updates them, otherwise attaches entity.