# Entity Tracked Problem After Upgrade .net 2.0 to .net 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, change-tracking

I am using repository pattern.
After upgrade .net 2.0 to 3.1 I got following error and I changed nothing.

```
The instance of entity type 'Table' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

1st solution is using AsNoTracking(). It is not a good solution, because when used this, EF don't update by field, EF update all fields. Also, I don't know which part of my code can get this error at runtime.

2nd solution is change entity state to modified. I can't apply this solution, because when I try to change state to modified I got following error. Actually I don't use any delete.

```
The association between entity types 'Table' and 'RelationalTable' has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.  Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values.
```

3rd solution is using scoped DbContext in startup.cs. It is already scoped and I also got this error on debugging I use single thread.

Finally, I didn't understand why I got this error after upgrade and how can I fix this problems, I don't want to test all operations.

Comment: Did you update the framework without any test? Have you the possibility to debug and add the code here?

Comment: Get [these extensions methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438914/10646316) and use `UpdateSafe`. It will prevent raising this exception.

Comment: The error is caused by Multiple entities  with the same key are tracked, Can you debug it to figure out which step cause this error? Because several common solutions have been posted in your question. You don't change anything just upgrade to .net 3.1 will show this error?

Comment: When I debuging with .net core 2.0 I can see that, EntityTable State is Modified, also I can see other relation EntityTable Object state is modified. However when I debug with the .net 3.1 only Relation EntityTable Object state is modified, entity table state is unchanged.