# What is the recommended way to determine whether an entity is tracked in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm working with EF Core in an ASP.NET Blazor application, where I often have service classes that handle saving data to the database. My save method typically looks like this:

```cs
public async Task SaveAsync(Entry entry)
{
    _context.Update(entry);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This approach has generally been working for me, but I recently realized that the `Update` method is marking all properties of the entity as modified, not just the ones that have actually changed. I found this out by using `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` and `Console.WriteLine(context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView)`.

Ideally, I want to call `Update` only when the entity is not being tracked. I've come up with three possible ways to check if an entity is tracked:

```cs
entry.Id == default
context.Entry(entry).State == EntityState.Detached
context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(x => x.Entity == entry)
```

I'm also dealing with occasional concurrency issues with the DB context, which leads me to sometimes use a separate DB context for querying and saving.

Considering these requirements, what would be the recommended way to determine if an entity is tracked, in terms of performance and reliability?

Also, is there a better pattern for handling saving of entities in EF Core, especially when dealing with a mix of new and existing entities?

Comment: Well, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438914/10646316) is complicated my solution. You can use `UpdateSafe`, it will check ChangeTracker for entry existence. Solution is complicate because of compiled expression caching for performance reason.