# EF Core issue with updating an entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a generic repository that has these two methods:

```
public virtual async Task<T> GetById(TId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    string key = GetCacheKeyById(id);
    return await base.GetFromCache(key,
            async () => { return await _dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id); },
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}

public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    var key = GetCacheKeyById(_dbContext.GetPrimaryKey<TId>(entity));
    _dbContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
    DeleteFromCache(key);
}
```

And I'm having issues when I try to update an entity.

My issue is that because on the validation layer I do a call to the `GetById` method to retrieve an entity it gets saved in the cache.

And later, in the business layer I do another call to `GetById` to get the entity that needs to be updated, set some properties on it and then call the `Update`.

This throws an exception with the message:

> The instance of entity type 'entity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

This seems fair since the entity that I'm updating is read from the cache and it's not the tracked entity.

Now I was thinking to add an optional parameter to the `GetById` to not read from cache and get the entity directly from the `dbContext` which should give me the tracked entity and that should work, but it seems ugly. The `dbContext` is scoped so it's the same instance in the validator and the business layer.

Is there a better/cleaner way of solving this problem?

Comment: What is `GetPrimaryKey`? Have you tried `_dbContext.AsNoTracking().GetPrimaryKey<TId>(entity)`?

Comment: GetPrimaryKey is a method to get the PK so that I can invalidate the cache on update.

Basically I do two calls to GetById() and update the values on the result of the second call. 
First invocation of GetById() will get the entity from the dbContext.
Second invocation of GetById() will get the entity from the cache.
And when I update the result from the second invocation I get this error(The instance of entity type 'entity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.) because of the first invocation which is tracked.

Comment: Use the following instead of `FindAsync`: `return await _dbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id)`

Comment: I thought of that, but my repository is generic and some entities have a composite PK so I can't do e.Id

Comment: It is a problem of generic repositories - introduces complexity and new bugs. I would suggest my function [UpdateSafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438914/10646316) which takes care about `ChangeTracker`'s duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv. That's exactly what I was looking for.